# Renaming groupId in maven

Tags: java, maven, refactoring

I'm in a middle of a refactoring and house keeping process of a multi-module Maven3 project and I need to rename groupId and artifactId of some artifacts.

Is there a way to rename both groupId and artifactId?
I know I can use some find-and-replace tool like sed, but I'm wondering if there's a mojo like [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) (e.g.: `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.3-SNAPSHOT`) but for groupId and artifactId.

Comment: I'm not aware of a tool or a maven plugin that does this. I usually use the IDE and its search and replace features. Just be careful if you use the groupId for several artifactId's.

Comment: I've ended up using sed: `find ~/project/trunk -name "pom.xml" | xargs sed -i 's/<groupId>org.old.groupId<\/groupId>/<groupId>org.new.groupId<\/groupId>/g'`. It worked like a charm, but still I was curious if there was a mojo outwhere.

Comment: out of curiosity I found: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/PomMavenPlugin but it seems a bit old :)

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for. Quite a pity it is pretty much abandoned...

Comment: @wemu You should add an answer. A solving comment is harder to find by others asking the same 

Comment: sometimes searching and using a tool is slower than just doing it :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to rename both groupId and artifactId?

As of today, the answer to your question is simple:

- No, there is no such plugin for renaming.

#### Write your own Maven Plugin

I guess you might be able to write such a maven plugin, though.

You can include this field in your Mojo:

```java
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true)
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    private MavenProject project;
```

The `MavenProject` class has the methods you are looking for (`setArtifactId`, etc.).

In fact, the [`SetMojo`](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/versions/SetMojo.java) from the maven-version-plugin will do exactly this for you.

---

This answer will be updated as soon as there is such a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way i know of.

First  create the and move all java source according to the new groupId you are going to specify in the pom . rename the project folder to the new artifactId. update the .project file according to new artifactId.

Now right click on the project in eclipse and do update maven project. If its updated without any errors you are good to go .

Answer (score -3):

Simple solution would be use textpad or notepad++ or other tool as you said sed and use find in file and replace the group id and artifact ids.

Comment: I think asker was looking for a solution that doesn't use a text editor but a specific tool designed to change group and artifact ids.

Comment: Yes, (though it was long ago) the idea was to update several child projects (pom.xml) in a bulk way, hopefully using maven and avoid manual edits.

Comment: This is a manual method and we are looking for automated solution for this.